# Update all fields of a column using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two local variables X and Y (the values can change) and column Z with different values for each row. How can I loop through all Z values and changed its value to X * Y * Z ?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop for this:

```
declare
    x integer := 10;
    y integer := 20;
begin
    update your_table set z = x * y * z;
end;
/
```